# Cannot find module 'models/PermissionModel' error when I try to require my javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I created a folder called models under my node server project
inside it a javascript file called PermissionModel.js

```
   var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema,
Objectid=Schema.Objectid;

var permissionSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
        docType:'string',
        permission:'array'

});
var PermissionModel=mongoose.model('permission',permissionSchema);

module.exports=PermissionModel;
```

then I try to import it inside my server.js file

```
var PermissionModel=require('models/PermissionModel');
```

when try to run my node project this error occured

```
Cannot find module 'models/PermissionModel'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sankha/Documents/Projects/HealthApp/blu_kross_server/server.js:4:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

please help me to solve this
thank you very much!!

Comment: where is PermissionModel.js located on the file system in relation to server.js?

Comment: try `var PermissionModel=require('/models/PermissionModel');` or check your file location on server

Comment: I tried but not working yet,

Comment: @SankaSumadura In that case please see the answer provided by yeya.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your require line to:

```
var PermissionModel=require('./models/PermissionModel');
```

If you don't put the `.` before the model, Node will look for the module only inside node_modules folder.

For further information read the docs of node, you can also ask google and find  [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm)

Answer (score 1):

inside your models directory create a file **index.js**
then export PermissionModel.js in your index.js file

```
exports.PermissionModel = require('./PermissionModel');
```

inside your **server.js** import the whole directory as below

```
var PermissionModel=require('./models');
```